# WPF menus open right alinged

Tags: wpf, menu-items

I have a top menu bar that has several drop down menus.

Currently when you open a menu, its child menu opens aligned on the left.
Is there a way I can shift that alignment to the right.
I have read a few things where I could change the system properties from left to right handed etc, but I just want this case to be purely for this particular menu.

Example:

From this

[image]

To this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to achieve what you want. Assume there is a menu like:

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="AAA" SubmenuOpened="MenuItem_SubmenuOpened">
        <MenuItem Header="111"/>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Then in code-behind, we can adjust the `Popup` of sub-menu like:

```
private void MenuItem_SubmenuOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem owner = (MenuItem)sender;
    Popup child = (Popup)owner.Template.FindName("PART_Popup", owner);

    child.Placement = PlacementMode.Left;
    child.HorizontalOffset = owner.ActualWidth;
    child.VerticalOffset = owner.ActualHeight;
}
```

Comment: @ megabytes Glad to help. I just found out there a mistake that will cause unnecessary measuring. I will correct my answer.

Comment: i've found that removing the:
if(!child.Child.IsMeasureValid)
{
    child.Child.Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));
}
code, there is a delay in the correct positioning of the menu.  It doesn't appear to update until I actually mouse over the menu itself - which i do kinda find odd.